# Why two different variables have the same address but different value in the below code?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

Check the value of `a` and `p[1]` and the address:

```
#include<stdio.h>

 main()
{
    int a=10,*p,c=20,n,i;
    printf("---&a is %p\n",&a);
    printf("---&p is %p\n",&p);
    printf("---&c is %p\n",&c);
    printf("---a is %d\n",a);
    printf("---p is %d\n",p);
    printf("---c is %d\n",c);

    printf("Enter size: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter ele: ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&p[i]);
    }

    printf("---&p[1] is &p\n",&p[1]);
    printf("---&p+1 is &p\n",&p+1);
    printf("---a is &d\n",a);
    printf("---p[1] is &d\n",&p[1]);
    printf("---p+1 is &p\n",&p+1);  
    printf("---a is &p\n",a);
    printf("---&a is &p\n",&a);
    printf("---c4 is &p\n",c);
    printf("---&c is &p\n",&c);
}
```

Here the value of `a` and `p[1]` is different although the address is the same,  why?

Comment: It doesn't appear that you've assigned a value to `p`.

Comment: `p` is not initalised. So `&p[1]` is an indeterminate value. In short, the code is invalid.

Comment: Code isn't invalid!! Firstly, I printed garbage value but then I used scanf to assign value!!

Comment: `p` is uninitialised, so it doesn't point at any object. That makes the use of `&p[i]` invalid. It would be fine if the value of `p` were the address of a region of memory sufficiently large to store 10 `int` values. But it has no assigned value, much less the address of an object.

Comment: This is no different from declaring an uninitialised `int` and then trying to use it in an arithmetic expression. (`int base;  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) printf("%d\n", base + i);`).

Answer (score 2):

`p[1]` is (by definition) `*(p + 1)`. `p + 1` is *not* the same as `&p + 1` because `&p` is the address of the variable `p` whereas `p` is the contents of the memory at that address.

There are also a number of problems with your code.

As it turns out, `&p + 1` is legal and well-defined, although you cannot dereference it (That is, you cannot use `*(&p +1)`.) The address is valid because pointer arithmetic lets you treat non-array variables as though they were arrays of length 1, and for any array, you can compute the address one element beyond the end of the array. You're not allowed to dereference the one-past-the-end address, but you can compare the address with a pointer which points at a real array element.)

You also can't compute `*(p+1)` because `p` hasn't been initialised and so you can't add 1 to it, nor you can you use the uninitialised value as a pointer. (It's not pointing at anything.)

Comment: Sir, but in scanf that's valid , right? (p[i]). And p+i is same as the p[i] and i didn't used *(p+1). Please have a look again. In addition, by writing &p+1 it means &(p+1) but we can not use brackets. To the best of my knowledge, &p[i] and &p+i is same and valid.  Pointer p has some address and +1 means to store the value in the next address of p. I mean if address of p is 1000 then  address of p+1 would be 1002 and so on. So, where is the problem? EXPLAIN ME IF I AM WRONG. I AM IN DOUBT, PLEASE HELP ME!

Comment: @zeel: Almost all of that is wrong. (1) if `p` is `int*`, `p[i]` is not valid as a `scanf` argument. You need to use `&p[i]` or `p+i`. (2) `p+i` is not the same as `p[i]`. It is the same as `&p[i]`. (3) `&p+1` is `(&p)+1`. Just like any other prefix operator. (4) `&(p+1)` is invalid because you cannot take the address of a temporary value. (5) You need to understand the difference between an address and a value. If `p` is an `int` and its value is 42, then `p+1`  is 43, regardless of the address of `p`. "The address of `p+1`" is meaningless because temporary values are not stored anywhere.

Comment: @zeel: Please try to remember that values and addresses are different things. Even if a variable is a pointer (`int *p`), it has an address and it has a value (which is stored at that address). `&` means "the address of". `*p` means "the object whose address is the value of `p`". `p[i]` is exactly the same as `*(p+i)`; that its definition. So `&p[i]` is `&(*(p+i))`, which is `p+i`. (Look at the definitions of `&` and `*` to understand why `&*x` is `x` for any pointer value `x`: the address of the object whose address is the value of x".

Comment: Actually when I wrote `p[i]` i meant `&p[i]`. And if I store a value in `&p+1` will it be the same as of `&p[i]`? If yes, check my code and run it! Reply Me

Comment: @zeel: No. I've said this several times now and I don't like having to repeat myself. From previous comment; "(2) `p+i` is not the same as `p[i]`. It is the same as `&p[i]`." From the answer: "`p + 1` is not the same as `&p + 1` because `&p` is the address of the variable `p` whereas `p` is the contents of the memory at that address."

Comment: @zeel: also see my comment on your question. Your code is broken because `p` is not initialised. I don't need to run it to see that.

Comment: what you mean by not initialised ?? I got that &p[i] and above in my comment I said that I mistakenly wrote p[i] instead of &p[i]. My concepts of &( address of ) is clear. Thanks for help!!

Comment: I tried by initialising pointer but facing the same problem the address of `a` and `p[1]` is same. Please check it. In addition the address of `p[1]` and `p+1` is different!!